# Email Application in android

Tags: android, email

I am working on a new module of Email application in android.

My main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
                 <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
                 <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Its working fine. 
My query is:
I have 5 tabs(Compose mail,Inbox,Sentmail,Drafts and Contacts). On clicking the respective tab I need to display corresponding application.
Eg. Wen i click on Compose mail tab, I need to compose mail application to get displayed and wen i click Inbox tab i need to display Inbox mails and so on.

Can some body help me in this issue?

Pls refer me any links for complete mailbox application source code.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: if you're looking for the complete source code for a mail client, let me suggest you either use a search engine, or hire a coder. this type of request is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Hello, TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) tutorial over on the Android developer site will explain what you need to do regarding your tabs.

You'll need an Activity for each tab, and you'll set up your tab host to switch between them like so (in your TabActivity):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
   TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
   TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
   Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

   // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
   intent = new Intent().setClass(this, InboxActivity.class);

   // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("inbox").setIndicator("Inbox",
                     res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_inbox))
                 .setContent(intent);
   tabHost.addTab(spec);

   ...
```

Comment: Can Any one suggest me code for Inbox and sent mails in android. I really googled a lot. Pls help me!!